# Способ передачи данных в поток bluetooth из другой activity (java android)

Tags: android, activity, bluetooth

Прошу помощи знающих людей чтобы направили на верный путь.
есть задача, передавать и принимать некоторые данные через bluetooth с андроид.
с этим, собственно, проблем не возникло. На основе множества примеров (основной, это мессенджер), в главной активити сделан поток для приема и передачи сообщений с последующей обработкой в handler.
Появилась потребность отправлять, а в идеале, и принимать данные по bluetooth из другой активности, отличной от главной. 
Собственно вопрос, есть ли возможность передать/получить данные в поток/из потока главной активности в/из другой активности.
Вариант с Intent for result не подходит, хотя бы потому, что требует закрытия активности.

пока, основываясь на малом опыте, зреет мысль, сделать следующий "костыль".
при переходе на другую активность, останавливать поток, разорвать сокет(если было соединение), а в новой активности все заново, новый поток, новый обработчик и тд, почти тоже что и в главной активности но с чуть другим набором данных для отправки/получения. (команды простые, в зависимости от содержимого полей, чекбоксов и пр. формируется байтовый массив, который и отправляется/принимается)

Есть ли способ сделать это более грамотно и аккуратно.
Прошу так же учесть, что писать под андроид я начал совсем недавно, посему опыта и знаний весьма мало, но способен на обучение.
прошу лишь указать направление в котором "копать".

Comment: Примените паттерн наблюдатель (observer).

Comment: Похоже что это то, что надо, буду разбираться.. спасибо большое. о результате отпишу.